# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"_popupComponentRef"' can't be used to index type 'MatDatepicker<Date>'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, datepicker, ngxs

They gave me this error :  *Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"_popupComponentRef"' can't be used to index type 'MatDatepicker'.
Property '_popupComponentRef' does not exist on type 'MatDatepicker'*

Please Help me with this problem.

On this line of code :  `{this._picker['_popupComponentRef'].instance._calendar.monthView._createWeekCells()`

**Here is my TS code :**

```
import {MatDatepicker, MatDatepickerInputEvent} from '@angular/material/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-demandeMultipleDays',
  templateUrl: './demandeMultipleDays.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./demandeMultipleDays.component.css']
})
export class DemandeMultipleDaysComponent implements OnInit {
  // private _popupComponentRef: ComponentRef<MatTimeSelectContentComponent<D>>;
  public CLOSE_ON_SELECTED = false;
  public init = new Date();
  public resetModel = new Date(0);
  public model = [
    new Date('7/15/1966'),
    new Date('3/23/1968'),
    new Date('7/4/1992'),
    new Date('1/25/1994'),
    new Date('6/17/1998')
  ];
  @ViewChild('picker', { static: true }) _picker: MatDatepicker<Date>;

  public dateClass = (date: Date) => {
    if (this._findDate(date) !== -1) {
      return [ 'selected' ];
    }
    return [ ];
  }

  public dateChanged(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>): void {
    if (event.value) {
      const date = event.value;
      const index = this._findDate(date);
      if (index === -1) {
        this.model.push(date);
      } else {
        this.model.splice(index, 1)
      }
      this.resetModel = new Date(0);
      if (!this.CLOSE_ON_SELECTED) {
        const closeFn = this._picker.close;
        this._picker.close = () => { };
        this._picker['_popupComponentRef'].instance._calendar.monthView._createWeekCells()
        setTimeout(() => {
          this._picker.close = closeFn;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  public remove(date: Date): void {
    const index = this._findDate(date);
    this.model.splice(index, 1)
  }

  private _findDate(date: Date): number {
    return this.model.map((m) => +m).indexOf(+date);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**And this is my HTML code :**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Choose a date" (click)="picker.open()">
    <mat-chip
      *ngFor="let value of model"
      [selectable]="false"
      [removable]="true"
      (removed)="remove(value)"
    >
      {{ value | date }}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="true">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input
      [value]="resetModel"
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="picker"
      placeholder="Choose a date"
      (dateChange)="dateChanged($event)"
      [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
      hidden
    />
  </mat-chip-list>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matPrefix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker
    #picker
    [startAt]="init"
    [dateClass]="dateClass"
  ></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**The expecting final result is:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZRgw.jpg)

But without the line where is the problem, no color appeared when clicking a date.

i'm using `npm i ngx-multiple-dates@13.1.0` and Angular `Angular CLI: 13.2.0`

The problem i'm having:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdJny.gif)

Code error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJR20.png)

Comment: I have no experience with ngx-multiple-dates, but as the error suggests it seems that the problem is that you're trying to access a property of _picker (`_popupComponentRef`)  which does not exist or is private. I've checked the docs for the package and it seems the cells get updated automatically by it, what was the reason to need to call `_createWeekCells` manually?

Comment: Hey Keff, i did that to update cell when the user click on a date, the problem is that the cells get colored after i reopen the datepicker. Normally, i need it to get updated just after clicking on a date. You can see in the following link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multiple-dates?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts) it did worked fine but not for me in my project.

Comment: @Keff you can see more information in the comment and the gif mentioned in the post. And thank you for interacting with the post.

Comment: I've tried the stackblitz example, and it works fine for me. Cells get updated each time I click on a cell. Is that the expected behaviour? Or does it work there for you too and fail locally?

Comment: @Keff Yes that's the expected behaviour but it fails to work in my local. I get the error in that particular lineof code.

Comment: Does the error appear at buildtime or at runtime?

Comment: Take a look in the post i added a screenshot of the error "Code error"

Comment: A hacky solution would be to cast this._picker to type any to remove the error `(this._picker as any)['_popupComponentRef']`, though I think this should not be done. Private fields are usually private for a reason, so I would recommend trying to accomplish what you wanted to do without accessing private fields.

Comment: I tried that but its not working. When i casted it to any, the error don't appear but i get an error in the runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use this simple
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multiple-dates?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.css

Try to change this._picker['_popupComponentRef'].instance._calendar.monthView._createWeekCells()
on this._picker['_componentRef'].instance._calendar.monthView._createWeekCells()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance with this matter.